# Is "My hand slipped me out of sleep asking where am I" correctly phrased?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request, idiomatic-language

> My hand slipped me out of sleep asking where am I

It sounds a bit off but I'm not sure if its correct. If it isn't, what's the most concise way to say that sentence?

What it means is 'my hand slipped and I woke up asking where am I' but I'm trying to directly link the slipping to the the waking to the asking.

Comment: "My hand  slipped me out of sleep" does not make sense; though you might meet it in poetry, where sometimes poets use word in non-standard ways, and may relish the ambiguity that that creates.

Answer (score 1):

That does sound awkward. Maybe "My hand slipped, and I woke up disoriented." The conjunction is all you need to imply that the first caused the second.